# Trajectory & Orbit of Simple ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let's start with $\frac{d}{dt} x(t)=ax(t)$

Obviously $x(t)=e^{at}$.  So the trajectory for some $a$ is going to be:

$T_a=${$(t,e^{at})|t \in \Bbb R$}

Now, is the orbit just {$x \in \Bbb R|x>0$}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $x(t)=ce^{at}$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$, with $t\in\mathbb R$. An you have one trajectory for each $c$, not for each $a$ (which is supposed to keep fixed).

So the orbit is $\{0\}$ for $c=0$, $(0,+\infty)$ for $c>0$, and $(-\infty,0)$ for $c<0$.

Comment: Okay, so generally speaking, to find an orbit, we do not need to "de-parameterize" the system of t? Can we just map $(t,x(t)) \to x(t)$

Comment: If you are talking about equations on $\mathbb R$ it is much simpler: the orbits are the points where the right-hand side vanishes (equilibria) and each interval that remains after erasing them. Example: for $x'=x(1-x)$ the orbits are $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$, $(-\infty,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,+\infty)$. Simple, right?

Comment: For the general case in $R^n$, is that why we end up looking at eigenvalues/eigenvectors?

Comment: No! But on the other hand: everything in $\mathbb R^n$ is **much** more difficult and we need to start somewhere, leading to consider first the linear case, and thus eigenvalues and eigenvectors (or better: Jordan forms).